# Can a vector of a-a, still be used as a point of direction even if it does equate to 0?

Tags: vectors

[image]

In my maths class we had a similar problem where we had to find the solution to get to **Y** from **X**. The answer is **c** however I argued that it could also be **a-a**, because technically you can go up to **B** from **X** by 1a and then down to **Y** by -1a, but apparently I was wrong, although I don't see why. Is **X** to **Y** simply **c**, or is my point (**a-a**) still technically correct, even if it does equate to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that $-1a$ will take you from $B$ back to $X,$ so $a-a$ takes from from $X$ to $X$.

We can get from $X$ to $Y$ directly by $c,$ or indirectly by $a+b$ (or many other, more complicated combinations, all of which simply amount to $c$).

Bear in mind that a vector is not just a magnitude (distance), but a *direction*. So, while it appears that $a$ and $b$ have the same magnitude by the drawing, the vector $a$ will not take us from $B$ to $Y$. The vector $b$ *will* do that, which is why $a+b$ does the trick (we could think of it as taking us from $X$ to $B$ to $Y$, or from $X$ to $Z$ to $Y$), but note that $a+b=c,$ so the simplest answer is $c$.

Comment: just trying to make sense of this all. Would the vector 'b' do the trick because it is parallel to BY, so they must be the same magnitude?

Comment: Assuming that all lines that *look* parallel actually *are* parallel, then $b$ will take us from $B$ to $Y$. It will not take us from $X$ to $Y$ on its own, though.

Comment: So even if two lines look parallel, does that mean they may not be parallel? If the answer is yes, then whats to say that BY can't also be equal to 'a' just as XY is, cos I read somewhere that vectors can still be equal and be anywhere on a page?

Comment: And another question: is the arrow pointing down labelled 'b' be negative b (if it's going down) or positive b, because it's labelled as a positive b.

Comment: I assume that $X,Y,Z$ are supposed to be the respective midpoints of the segments $AB,BC,AC,$ so *apparently* parallel is *actually* parallel. Also, we necessarily have that the segments $AX,BX,YZ$ are the same length; $BY,CY,XZ$ are the same length; $AZ,CZ,XY$ are the same length. It certainly *looks* like the first two sets of three segments are all equal in length to each other in length, but even if so, they are *not in the same direction*. Magnitude *and* direction are important. We treat vectors the same regardless of their starting point *if they have the same magnitude and direction*.

Comment: As for $b$, the arrow indicates the direction of $b$. The vector $-b$ is the vector that takes us (for example) from $Z$ to $X$ or from $Y$ to $B$.